# PHP - Default function arguments

Tags: php, function

Should empty function arguments be set to `NULL` or `FALSE`?

As example follows:

```
function test1($a = FALSE, $b = FALSE)
{
    if ($b)
    {
        // ... (some awesome code here)
    }

    //.. (more awesome code)
}

test1(0);
```

**OR**

```
function test2($a = NULL, $b = NULL)
{
    if ($b !== NULL)
    {
        // ... (some awesome code here)
    }

    //.. (more awesome code)
}

test2(0);
```

Note; Also something to consider - while using `$a === NULL`. One could also use '`!empty()`' depending if the below code requires empty values or not.

Which is a better design and why?

Comment: Option 3 *might* be the best. Have separate functions. But with the provided info it's pretty much impossible to say which one of the three is "the better design".

Comment: Do you have 3 cases or just 2?  I.e., are you going to do something different if '$a == false' versus 'isset( $a ) == false'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically a `NULL` value should treat as something that doesn't exist. `FALSE` instead has some semantic value, even if you can consider it as an empty value.

So, use `FALSE` for an answer to yes or no, `NULL` as no answer.
If your argument is an option like `$enable_this` it can be a boolean value, and you may want check if it's true with

```
if ($var)
```

Instead if you can optionally pass something as an argument, by default it can be `NULL`, and then you can check if it's really there with

```
if($var !== null)
```

You should use `empty` only if you want test it to empty value. Cannot `$var` be an empty string, an empty array, `"0"` or `0`?

Comment: So you suggest if the optional parameter is a `boolean` then it should be `FALSE/TRUE ` and if it's `integer`, `string`, `array`, or `object` then it should be `NULL` ?

Comment: That depends on what you're doing. There are some case when you want use `NULL` by default even when the parameter can be a boolean. Use `NULL` as a `there-is-nothing-here`.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this**

```
function test($a = NULL, $b = NULL)
{
    if ($b !== NULL)
    {
        // ... (some awesome code here)
    }

    //.. (more awesome code)
}

test(0);
```

Dont use `if(!empty($b))`, `if($b!=NULL)` and `if(!is_null($b))` because `$b=false` && `$b=0` will fail in this case

Comment: i was here for writing that

Comment: There's also `is_null($b)`

Comment: is_null($b) too. Tanx @321zeno

Comment: So using `NULL` over `FALSE` is better for empty default functions?!

I updated with my code with the tighter conditional statement ;-)

Comment: @tfont yes. Use null instead of false for empty default functions. Also mark your accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

```
function test1($a = FALSE, $b = FALSE) {
  if ($b===false) {
    // ... (process default val-false)
  }else{
    //.. (process supplied value)
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. But thank you for your method. I suppose that you would suggest using `FALSE` over `NULL` then.

Comment: yes i do prefer a FALSE over NULL as default value for just one simple reason - False is a value and NULL is not.